# How to use getSupportFragmentManager() in fragment?

Tags: java, android

I am unable to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` inside my
`Schedule_fragment`. Any help how can I use it ? I am new to this so if any silly mistake please correct me.

```
public class Schedule_fragment extends Fragment implements TimePickerFragment.TimePickerListener{
    private TextView displaytime;
    View view;
    public Schedule_fragment() {

    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_fragment,container,false);
        return view;
        displaytime=view.findViewById(R.id.displaytime);
        Button showtime=view.findViewById(R.id.showtime);
        showtime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                DialogFragment timePickerFragment=new TimePickerFragment();
                timePickerFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"timePicker");
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int minute) {
        displaytime.setText("Hour = " +hour + "Minute = "+ minute);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add fragments as children of your fragment you can use `getChildFragmentManager()`. On the other hand, if you try to add/remove/... the fragment of the activity you must call `getSupportFragmentManager()` on the activity instance. The activity instance is available by calling `getActivity()` (this will only be valid while the activity is active).

Comment: I want to make this clock implement in this fragment . How can i do it?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. You can try to use `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` but this might not be the right solution. I can't tell because I don't know your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you extends `android.app.Fragment` the method `getFragmentManager()` will return a instance of `android.app.FragmentManager`

If you extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` the method `getFragmentManager()` will return a instance of `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` that is the same instance as of `FragmentActivity#getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: Thank you for this hint but now my this line 'displaytime=view.findViewById(R.id.displaytime);' shows error. – unreachable statement

Comment: You added a return somewhere, its not related to the question